# How to check image source in if statement? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to figure out how to check an image source in an if statement, which would then disable a button, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the program correctly tell what the source is.
This is what I have so far:

```
function sick() {
        if (document.getElementById("relaxed").src == "Sick.jpg") {
            document.getElementById("play").disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<img src="Rel.jpg" alt="rel" id="relaxed">
<button onclick="sick()" id="feed">Feed</button>
<button onclick="play()" id="play">Play</button>
```

Comment: how's the function being called ?

Comment: onclick of another button.

Comment: It should work, can you provide a code snippet, so we can reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Just updated the post with the two buttons I'm using for this

Comment: keep in mind that the `src` property will return the absolute path to the image not just it's name try this `console.log(document.getElementById("relaxed").src);` so you can see, so you'll have to adjust your if statement.

Comment: So would I just delete the .src?

Comment: No you'll have to extract the name from it then check it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help!